# The inner mechanism of WP SEO plugins

Tags: seo, wordpress

This is more of a conceptual question, but it has actual ramifications.

Going through the various SEO plugins I found nowhere a PHP tag that should be embedded in the actual HTML page and echo the meta data. How does it work then?

Simply saving it to the DB doesn't seem enough. What is the mechanism through which the plugin "injects" the SEO data to the page? and what if I have my own `meta` tag in the page - Would it override the plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mechanisms are usually [FILTERS](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Filters) and [ACTIONS](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Actions) hooks from the wordpress [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API)

This is not particular to the SEO plugins, but to almost all the plugins that change actual content .

simply put :

> Action Hooks

Actions Hooks are designs to be used when WordPress core itself, some plugin or theme is giving you a special "breakpoint"  to insert your code in order to do some action, or change something while a certain action is triggered .

> Filter Hooks :

Filter Hooks are very similar to Action Hooks but what they do is to receive a value and potentially return a modified version of that value.

**UPDATE I**

see this simple example (put in your theme´s function.php

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );

function my_the_content_filter(){

echo ':::::: THIS CONTENT WILL BE ADDED TO ANY POST :::::';

}
```

or this :

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_the_title_filter' );

function my_the_title_filter(){
echo ':::::: THIS CONTENT WILL BE ADDED TO ANY TITLE :::::';
}
```

**UPDATE II**

IF however, your question is actually about how SEO works, and not the plugin itself :
SEO is a big subject, but simply put , it is about the meta-tags, titles, descriptions, links, rels etc ... this is what the SEO plugins are changing .

They change things like -

- adding automatic descriptions and titles to images
- changing page titles
- adding meta tags by post
- etc etc...

.. - but they all use the above mentioned mechanism of *`actions` and `filters` hooks*. the fact that you do not *see* it in the code, is that you do not know what to look for .

Try to save the page source BEFORE and AFTER the plugin activation, and then do a diff on both. You will see the differences ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While I'm somewhat familiar with the concept of actions and filters as a way to intervene in the "life-cycle" of Wordpress, I do see the injected mark-up when I view page source(e.g when creating a meta box). This isn't the case with SEO plugin. Or is it?

Comment: this is exactly the same , just using different hooks and actions, some are designed for the FRONT end , and some to operate on the 'CONTENT' - which can be title, meta-data, sidebar, actual post or whatever - which is the real `source code` that you are referring to. I suggest you read the link I had posted , and you will understand better . SEO plugins are no different in the way they operate from any other plugin ... see my update for example

Comment: Thanks for update II, but my question was that in fact, even with the plugin activated I see **no** meta tags in the HTML doc as received from the server.

Comment: Then either the plugin does not work, or you did not configured it correctly , or this particular plugin does not support meta-tags . look at different aspects and plugins also .